# ImportError: No module named SQLAlchemy with Anaconda

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have a python script that works on all other remote servers I've run it on but for some reason on a particular remote server where I have Anaconda installed I'm getting an ImportError for SQLAlchemy. I am connecting to a MySQL db.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, mapper
import sys
dev_engine = create_engine('mysql://...')
prod_engine  = create_engine('mysql://...')

def transactions(exchange, filepath):
    dev_connect = dev_engine.connect()
    prod_connect = prod_engine.connect()

    get_dev_instrument = "select * from " + exchange + "_instrument;"
    instruments = dev_engine.execute(get_dev_instrument)
    instruments_list = [r for r in instruments]
    get_prod_instrument = "select * from " + exchange + "_instrument;"
    instruments_after = prod_engine.execute(get_prod_instrument)
    instruments_after_list = [r2 for r2 in instruments_after]

    ...
```

I am getting the following error when trying to run it.

```
  File "/home/local/filepath/general.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import *
  ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

However if I run the python shell, I can import sqlalchemy

```
my.username@remote-server:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>>
```

What is wrong?

EDIT: If I call my script from its directory, it works perfectly fine. I am calling the script using the full filepath since I am trying to run it from Crontab.

```
my.username@remote-server:~$ python general.py arg1 arg2
formed maps
my.username@remote-server:~$

my.username@remote-server:~$: /usr/bin/python /home/local/TMG/filepath/general.py arg1 arg2


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/local/TMG/filepath/general.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import *
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

Comment: what do you get when you do the following from the scripts directory? `import sys
print sys.path
`

Comment: `import.im6: unable to open X server \`' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/368.`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/local/TMG/filepath")
```

in the very beginning of your script.

Comment: Use which python to ensure the default python you are using. It looks like your default python is not /usr/bin/python

Comment: it's using anaconda's python

Comment: that was the error. I ran it with `/usr/bin/python` instead of anaconda's python. thanks

Comment: quick question, if I'm using anaconda's python, do I need to change it in my shebang as well?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is anaconda's python. Basically, you can install the required packages if you can control the python env.